# ApplicationContextException: Initializer class does not implement ApplicationContextInitializer interface

Tags: java, spring, jetty, spring-web

I am on a macOS High Sierra (Version 10.13.2) and I am using java version 1.8.0_151 through IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.2 (Community Edition). I am trying to run locally a JAR but the following exception is thrown:

```
    [main] ERROR ContextLoader:350 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Initializer class does not implement ApplicationContextInitializer interface: class xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.PropertyContextInitializer
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.loadInitializerClass(ContextLoader.java:520)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.determineContextInitializerClasses(ContextLoader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.customizeContext(ContextLoader.java:465)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:843)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.AFJetty.start(AFJetty.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx.AFJettyMain.main(AFJettyMain.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.snapShooter.SnapShooter.main(SnapShooter.java:59)
```

The corresponding lines of PropertyContextInitializer are the following:

```
Class<?> clazz = ClassUtils.forName(className, ClassUtils.getDefaultClassLoader());
if (!ApplicationContextInitializer.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
    throw new ApplicationContextException("Initializer class does not implement ApplicationContextInitializer interface: " + clazz);
}
```

While

```
ApplicationContextInitializer.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)
```

is false with clazz being "class xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.PropertyContextInitializer", the expression

```
ApplicationContextInitializer.class.isAssignableFrom(xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.PropertyContextInitializer.class)
```

evaluates to true! And, in fact, the class PropertyContextInitializer has the following definition:

```
public class PropertyContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
```

and it builds fine, so I really cannot understand why such exception is thrown. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are doing strange things in your startup class. Starting a server yourself, trying to deploy something. You are running into class loading issues a class is assignable if it also resides in the same classloader. The same class in different class loader will lead to class cast exceptions.

Comment: Are you sure the ApplicationContextInitializer<?> you implement is the Spring one ?

Comment: @M.Deinum, I think you set me to the right path, I guess I am using different class loader here.

Comment: @Julien, thanks but yeah, it is the Spring one.

Comment: @JacopoLanzoni it's worth having a look ;)